# Selecting multiple tables and unions in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I'm doing a project in Laravel that is an update over an older Vanilla PHP project and I've encountered a query that I can't quite replicate in Laravel.

I need some help with it. The idea is simply getting a count of all e-mails in any of the tables mentioned in the query that match the e-mail given by the user. Also, email creation date, according to their respective tables, should be greater than or equal to two days.

```
$sqlDuplicates = "
    select count(*) as total from (
        select distinct(email) from clientes where created_date>='".$data1."' and email = :txEmail
        union all (
        select distinct(txEmailC2L) from records_SegurosLogoC2L where dtCreated>='".$data1."' and txEmailC2L = :txEmail
        )
        union all (
        select distinct(txEmailC2L) from records_SimuleSegurosLogoC2L where dtCreated>='".$data1."' and txEmailC2L = :txEmail
        )
        union all (
        select distinct(email) from records_LogoOnline where created_date>='".$data1."' and email = :txEmail
        )
        union all (
        select distinct(email) from records_SegurosAutoEconomico where created_date>='".$data1."' and email = :txEmail
        )
        union all (
        select distinct(email) from records_SimuleSegurosLogo where created_date>='".$data1."' and email = :txEmail
        )
    ) as data
";
```

That is the query. If anyone is able to help, I would appreciate it

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/queries#unions Should help you get started

Answer (score 0):

The correct sintax in Laravel 5 is:

```
    $sqlDuplicates = DB::table('f_table_name')
                    ->join('s_table_name', 'f_table_name.id', '=', 's_table_name.photo_id')
                    ->where('created_date', '>=', $date)
                    ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
                    ->get();
```